# Session timeout increases tremendously when the user picks to stay in the system by clicking a button (asp.net mvc 5.0 using OWIN)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-identity, owin

I am trying to implement session timeout popup. I have made a fair progress. Everything seems to work fine except when the user clicks the "Stay in the system" button in the popup window. What this button does is to make an ajax call to the following `Action` in the `Account Controller`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> RefreshTheUserSession(string UserId)//this will be called from the ajax timeout
{       
    var myuser = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(UserId);

    if (myuser != null)
    {
         await SignInManager.SignInAsync(myuser, true, true);
    }
    return null;
 }
```

This could works fine and keeps the user in the system. However, the new session timeout timespan becomes around **1209596**. This value is initially set to 2 minutes for testing purposes as shown in the following (`Startup.Auth.cs`).

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
 {
      AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
      LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Index"),
      ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
      Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
      {     
            OnValidateIdentity = MyCustomValidateIdentity
      }
 });
```

And, actually, when the user logins the system for the first time, the ExpireTimeSpan is set to 2 mins correctly. However, when the time comes for the user to click to stay in the system, the session timeout timespan gets crazy.

Here is the login code just in case:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         return View(model);
    }

    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
             return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
             return View("Lockout");
    }
}
```

Later, I have added this in the `Web.Config`, but did not help. (and not sure it would help since I am using OWIN)

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20" />
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Why the session timeout value gets crazy when I try to (re)-sign in the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1209596 seconds is approximately 14 days, or 2 weeks. What you're doing here is setting the "remember me" flag for the user and that's exactly what it does. It sets the timeout on the user's auth cookie to 2 weeks, so the user is not required to login again for 2 weeks.

If that's not what you want, then change the action to:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> RefreshTheUserSession(string UserId)//this will be called from the ajax timeout
{       
    var myuser = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(UserId);

    if (myuser != null)
    {
         await SignInManager.SignInAsync(myuser);
    }
    return null;
}
```

In other words, don't pass `true` for the `isPersistent` or `rememberBrowser` params. You may also need to call `AuthenticationManager.SignOut()`, first, as it may not let you sign in an already signed in user. With the code you have now, you're technically updating the authentication by making it persistent, requiring a new cookie to be sent, so that's a little different.